# model->save() Not Working In Yii -> Show ' error '

Tags: php, database, for-loop, model

I source the real-time price form exchange market and keep them in database. So, was using $model->save() function for inserting or updating any data.  I don't know where i did mistake. The result shows ' error '. I don't know why it is error and how to fix it.

public function actionIndex()
    {

```
    for ($i=1; $i <=3 ; $i++) { 
        for ($j=1; $j <=4 ; $j++) {
            for ($k=1; $k <=4 ; $k++) {

                echo '<pre>';
                $coin_id = $i;
                $market_1 =$j;
                $market_2 =$k;

                $fee = 0.0025;

                $price_1 = PriceUs::model()->find('market_id='.$market_1.' AND coin_id='.$coin_id.' ORDER BY id DESC');
                $price_2 = PriceUs::model()->find('market_id='.$market_2.' AND coin_id='.$coin_id.' ORDER BY id DESC');

                $profit = (  ( 100 / (  ($price_1->offer_usd) / (1-$fee) ) ) *  (  ($price_2->bid_usd) * (1-$fee) )   ) - 100 ;

                $model=new Oneway;
                $model->create_at=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $model->coin_id=$coin_id;
                $model->market_id1=$market_1;
                $model->market_id2=$market_2;
                $model->profit_oneway=$profit;

                if($model->save())
                {
                    echo 'ok';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'error';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}[enter image description here][1]
```

The result show this 
ok
ok
error
ok
ok
error
ok
error
ok
ok
error
. 
.
.
It's mean some result can save but some cannot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of echoing the error in `else`, do as

```
print_r($model->getErrors());
```

this will redirect you to the correct error